# OpenCL C++: CL_INVALID_KERNEL and make_kernel not a member of cl

Tags: c++, opencl, member

I've been reading a lot here but this is my first post.

I'm trying to run C++ OpenCL code for Altera's FPGA, compatible OpenCL 1.0 only for now.
So far, preparing the environment, querying the platform and using other OpenCL functions works just fine. But when I try to create the kernel and add the arguments, I'm facing problems. I've tried two approaches and both come with their errors:

**Approach one:**

```
    auto simple_add = cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer&, cl::Buffer&, cl::Buffer&>    (opencl_Program, ocl_func_name.c_str());
    cl::EnqueueArgs eargs(queue, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(n), cl::NullRange);
    simple_add(eargs, buffer_A, buffer_B, buffer_C).wait();
```

Thsi yields the following compile error:

*error: ‘make_kernel’ is not a member of ‘cl’*

*auto simple_add = cl::make_kernel(opencl_Program, ocl_func_name.c_str());*

**Approach two:**

```
cl::Kernel simple_add = cl::Kernel(opencl_Program, ocl_func_name.c_str(), p_err);
if (p_err != NULL)
    display_OpenCL_ErrorCode(*p_err);

err = simple_add.setArg(0, sizeof(cl::Buffer), (void*)&buffer_A);
display_OpenCL_ErrorCode(err);

err = simple_add.setArg(1, sizeof(cl::Buffer), (void*)&buffer_B);
display_OpenCL_ErrorCode(err);

err = simple_add.setArg(2, sizeof(cl::Buffer), (void*)&buffer_C);
display_OpenCL_ErrorCode(err);
```

This yields the following runtime output code at each "setArg" line (creating the Kernel yields no error):

*-48 (i.e. CL_INVALID_KERNEL).*

My reasoning:

- I haven't been able to find anywhere any OpenCL 1.0 C++ documentation. It only seems to be available starting at version 1.2, so there might not be a way for me to write any code for the FPGA in C++ but I first wanted to make sure (still sounds unlikely to me though).
- The code from approach one comes from a prior file I created when using OpenCL 2.0 and C++11 and that worked fine. It's already documented in OpenCL 1.2 so it should probably work nonetheless?
- Even though the kernel creation seems to be flawless in the second approach, I'm suspecting it not to have worked as expected since it won't allow be to set any arguments to the linked function. But hard for me to debug that as there are no errors...

Any help and support appreciated!

(Didn't want to overload the first post, but if required I can post more code).

EDIT1: I had a look at the cl.hpp file and found the following line:
*   \brief C++ bindings for OpenCL 1.0 (rev 48) and OpenCL 1.1 (rev 33) 
So this confirms the fact that there is an OpenCL 1.0 C++ wrapper. 
What I also found out was that inside, there was no make_kernel function. I'll have a closer look at the file and post the corrected code if I come find a solution.

Comment: You can use the opencl C api with C++ if you want to check if the C++ api is causing your problems

Comment: Am I understanding that you see nothing wrong with the C++ implementation I documented above?

Comment: I normally use approach Two and that was working fine with Altera. No special requirements needed. I suggest to make it work first for OpenCL CPU or GPU and then go for Altera. You may also try setting `-DCL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION=100 -DCL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION=100` to enforce OpenCL 1.0 compatibility however I never needed to set that.

Answer (score 0):

I've also came cross the bug a few days ago and I just work it out. I'm here sharing the solution. This is the code:

```
inline void CreateOCLKernels()
{
    filterDepth_ocl_kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "filterDepthKernel", &clError);
    checkErr(clError, "clCreateKernel");
    convertDisparityToDepth_ocl_kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "convertDisparityToDepthKernel", &clError);
    checkErr(clError, "clCreateKernel");
    ComputeNormalAndWeight_ocl_kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "ComputeNormalAndWeightKernel", &clError);
    checkErr(clError, "clCreateKernel");
    convertDepthAffineToFloat_ocl_kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "convertDepthAffineToFloatKernel", &clError);
    checkErr(clError, "clCreateKernel");
}
ITMViewBuilder_OpenCL::ITMViewBuilder_OpenCL(const ITMRGBDCalib *calib):ITMViewBuilder(calib) { CreateOCLKernels(); }
```

As you can see, it's a inline function called by a constructor. And I keep receiving "invalid kernel name" from function "CreateOCLKernels()" until I add "static" to that function.

```
static inline void CreateOCLKernels()
{ ... }
```

I guess you must know why. Since a non-static function is global and there can be conflicts among functions from other files with the same name. **Since I didn't make it "static", some other function from other file is called instead of the correct local one.**